# How to change showing data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I take datas from json file and there is so much data inside because of this I don't want to show all. In the page I want to show just 20 data and when I click NEXT button i want to see another 20 data. It's working but in the filter function it update filteredDatas but don't update showingDatas

```
import data from './data.json'
var i = 0
var j = 20

function App() {
const [showingDatas, setShowingDatas] = useState([])
const [filteredDatas, setFilteredDatas] = useState([])

const getDatas = () =>{
 setFilteredDatas(data)
 setShowingDatas(data.slice(0,20))
}

useEffect(()=>{
getDatas()
},[])

const next = () => { 
 i += 20;
 j += 20;
 setShowingDatas(filteredDatas.slice(i,j)) 
}

const filter = () => {
 setFilteredDatas(data.filter(item => item.productCompany ===  "Mavi"))
 i = 0
 j = 20
 setShowingDatas(filteredDatas.slice(0,20))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can not do this like that, because of React working principles. But if you want to do that I suggest you use `useEffect` to keep `filteredData` changes, then in `useEffect` set it. Like:

```js
useEffect(() => {
   setShowingDatas(filteredDatas)
},  [filteredDatas]);
```

If you really want to do with `useState` I suggest you search `useState with callback`.

Comment: Thank you, i got it